# C# Proper Way to Close Multiple Excel Objects With Excel Process Destroyed

Tags: c#, excel, com, excel-interop

I have a C# console program. When it runs, it instantiates some Excel objects such as: (openExcelO).

When the program is done running, I have a method to close down Excel (closeExcel) and that is supposed to properly clean up the Excel process. In task manager I can see the remnants of Excel that remain. The shut down routines were cobbled together from internet examples:

```
    private void openExcelO (string dir) {

        try {
            xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(dir + "PortfolioOptimization5.xlsm",
                0, false, 5, "", "", true, 
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, 
                "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
            xlMarkowitz = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Sheets["Markowitz"];
            xlWeights = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Sheets["Weights"];

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ReportError("PortfolioOptimization", "openExcel", ex.ToString());
        }

    }


    private void closeExcel () {
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        try {

            if (xlWeights != null) releaseObject(xlWeights);
            if (xlMarkowitz != null) releaseObject(xlMarkowitz);

            xlWorkBook.Close(false, misValue, misValue);
            if (xlApp != null) xlApp.Quit();

            if (xlWorkBook != null) releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
            if (xlApp != null) releaseObject(xlApp);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ReportError("PortfolioOptimization", "closeExcel", ex.ToString());
        }
    }


    private void releaseObject (object obj) {
        try {
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
            obj = null;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            obj = null;
            ReportError("PortfolioOptimization", "releaseObject", "Unable to release object " + ex.ToString());
        } finally {
            GC.Collect();
        }
    }
```

How can I change the shutdown routine to properly shut down and clean up the Excel objects so there are no lingering Excel processes in the Task Manager?

Thanks!

Comment: You should probably try releasing the workbook immediately after you close it, _then_ close excel, _then_ release the application. Does `Quit` have a boolean overload to allow exit while ignoring all errors? The Word interop object does.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Proper way of closing Excel application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581689/proper-way-of-closing-excel-application)

Comment: Note also that in addition to the fact that you should always [think very hard before invoking `GC.Collect`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/118776/622391), your calls to `GC.Collect` won't actually help your object get collected, as your main class still holds a reference to each of your COM objects. To make `releaseObject` also clear the primary reference, change it to `releaseObject(ref object obj)`, because then when you invoke `obj = null`, the field itself will be set to null.

Comment: @KenWhite I see the similarity but feel this question and answer are more complete than the one referenced. I didn't see any other question that addressed the issue of sheet, workbook and app objects with order of destruction. I have marked Simon's answer so if you need to close the topic it is your call.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like you're not releasing your objects in the correct order - `xlApp.Quit` probably can't exit cleanly because you still hold a reference to the workbook. You need to release the workbook *before* you invoke `Quit`:

```
xlWorkBook.Close(false, misValue, misValue);
releaseObject(xlWorkBook);

xlApp.Quit();
releaseObject(xlApp);
```

Credit must go to [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/158752/622391): there are a couple of other implicit references that you're not closing, i.e., in the following lines:

```
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(...)
xlWorkBook.Sheets["Markowitz"];
```

The "Workbooks" object isn't being released, and neither is the "Sheets" object. You need to release these references too, i.e.:

```
var books = xlApp.Workbooks;
books.Open(...);
releaseObject(books);

var sheets = xlWorkBook.Sheets;
xlMarkowitz = (Excel.Worksheet)sheets["Markowitz"];
xlWeights = (Excel.Worksheet)sheets["Weights"];
releaseObject(sheets);
```

Great advice from [Bruce Barker](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/showpost.php?p=528575): "Never use two dots with COM objects"!

Comment: This is a very good answer Simon! It addresses the two problems in my code (order of object destruction and the catch with implicit references.) Thanks!